# CSS - Dynamically Remove Font Descender

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts

I am using `react-textfit` to automatically scale text to fit to a `div` of a specific width and height (which is a percentage of the window). The font I'm using has a massive descender (whitespace at the bottom). At a result, trying to center other elements inline with this text is difficult. Since the size of this text will change based on the screen size, I cannot manually change the line-height to fix this. Furthermore, using a variable line-height does not work, as the font is not centered around the text.

For example, in this image, you can see how there is significant whitespace below the character.

[image: Highlighted S]

A variable line height (70%) does not help either, since the whitespace at the bottom is treated as it is apart of the character itself. Thus, the character is not vertically centered within the `div`, which is the intended outcome. Manually setting a line height with a pixel value also fails in the same way.

[image: Variable line height]

Because the character has whitespace below it, inline elements that should be centered vertically alongside the text is instead shifted down.

[image: Uncentered]

The title, alongside the included inline elements are wrapped in the following `div`:

```
.title {
  width: 100%;

  margin-left: 4vw;

  height: 20vmin;
  display: inline-block;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

The title itself, is in the following `div`:

```
.title .text {
  height: 20vmin;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-flex;

  align-items: center;

  line-height: 1;
}
```

`react-textfit` will also give `.title .text` a font-size in pixels during runtime, so that it fits within a `height` of `20vmin` and a `width` of `80%`

Finally, `react-textfit` will wrap the text in another `div` with the following style:

```
display: block;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Essentially, at runtime, this is what the entire thing looks like:

```
<div class="title">
    <div class="text">
        <div style="display: block; white-space: nowrap">TITLE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="some-other-element-that-should-be-vertically aligned">...</div>
</div>
```

Is there anyway to use CSS to remove this excess whitespace at the bottom of this text so that other elements can be vertically aligned with it?

Example project (using normal HTML, not React): https://codesandbox.io/s/29-fonts-forked-vuvdx?file=/fonts.css

Comment: Any chance you can create a simple [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/) reproduction so we can play around with it?

Comment: @CallumMorrisson https://codesandbox.io/s/29-fonts-forked-vuvdx?file=/fonts.css. React wasn't working with uploaded fonts for whatever reason, so I mimicked the effect of react-textfit within a normal html project.

Comment: @Orion31 I would try with `em` on **box** for everything related to **title** font size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your codesandbox, I would try with `em` unit instead, that way everything (margin, padding, font-size, etc) will be always relative to the element (**title**) font-size:

```
.box {
  font-size: 0.5em;
  border: 0.1em solid black;
  height: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;

  margin: 0 0.1em 0;

  ...
}

.box span {
  margin-top: 0.2em;
}
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work because the font-size isn't being set for `.title`, but is automatically determined by `react-textfit` and only applies to `.text`. Otherwise, I think a margin-top in ems would work.

Comment: I understand that title may not have a specific font-size, but it does reference a font-size somewhere on the upper level, although if you say it doesn't work, then it doesn't work, hope you can have a way to put your real example so we can compare apples to apples.

Comment: I think I just get what you mean by applied to text and not tittle, any chance you can put the box inside .text?

Comment: Putting the box inside `.text` worked, thank you!